# Identify this British miniseries about a scientist

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I am looking for the name of a miniseries that I had watched a long time ago. It's plot was about a scientist and his apprentice in a university. 
The time line suggested it was between 1920s and 1950s maybe taking place in London.

> some more info about the episodes:
>
> 1. truth serum stolen and poured in London water system.
> 2. a scientist discovers a time slowing compound.
> 3. an electrical technician who does time travel by accident.

Comment: When is "a long time ago"? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for UK sci-fi mini-series [The Infinite Worlds of H.G. Wells](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280770/combined) from 2001, a historical 6-episode show based on the stories of H.G. Wells with him as the protagonist that investigates paranormal events with his girlfriend, teacher and scientist Jane Robbins. It includes:

- A truth serum released into London's water supply (Ep. 6, *The Stolen Bacillus*)
- A scientist inventing a compound that slows down time perception (Ep. 1, *The New Accelerator*)
- An electrical technician experiencing accidental time travel (Ep. 2, *Brownlow’s Newspaper*)

[image]