# Sci-fi thriller mini stories movie (90s-early 2000s)

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, thriller

I remember watching this movie as a kid but I can't get myself to recall the title. 
The movie is about this doctor/scientist/journalist at an old age who talks about his experiences with his young assistant as they travel to this site to investigate some strange occurances. In the movie the protagonist's experiences are showed as flashbacks mini stories.
Here is a list of those flashbacks from what I recall from the movie:

- He goes to this University to invastigate some strange happenings believed to be ghosts but he finds out about this guy who had studied this medicine that permitted him to move at hyperspeed, making him invisible to the human eye, for a limited amount of time.
- flashback 2: It starts with this really fat guy who desperatelly wants to lose weight and finds this "wonderous" merchant who sells him a potion to make him lighter. But he becomes literally light, without altering his volume, and starts floating around so the protagonist sticks lead mini-bars on his clothes to prevent him from floating away.
- flashback 3: In this house in a small town there is this couple that had found a strange egg, which glows in absence of light but if you looked at it for long enough it trapped you in a strange dimension.
- flashback 4: I recall this very very faintly; the protagonist visits this mental facility about strange happenings involving a copper coil device.

That's all I can remember.

Answer (score 8):

You're actually thinking of [The Infinite Worlds of H.G. Wells](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280770/combined), a three episode miniseries from 2001. It made a couple of appearances here (see [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33663/identify-this-british-miniseries-about-a-scientist/33699#33699) and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51856/tv-show-consisting-of-unrelated-episodes-mainly-about-science-fiction-from-the-e/51896#51896)), but your question is slightly different.

In it, an aging Wells recounts his past experiences to a young journalist, all based on his stories. The one with hyperspeed and invisibility is *The New Accelerator*, the one with the strange egg is *The Crystal Egg* and the one with the overweight man who becomes lighter than air is based on *The Truth About Pyecraft*. Here's a behind the scenes clip with the floating man, among others: